# Как именно "работают" SQL запросы?

Tags: sql

Мне интересна техническая сторона вопроса.
Поверх какого протокола реализован(ы) и работает(ют) SQL запрос(ы)?

Comment: обычно либо напрямую обращаются к базе (sqlite), либо через tcp (mysql, postres) либо через http (реже). А как именно запрос внутри упаковывается - это личное дело каждой базы.

Comment: > Поверх какого протокола?
Когда вы набираете команду `sqlite` или ей подобную, за работу такого режима отвечает [readline](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline)

Comment: В таком виде вопрос слишком общий. По каждой из существующих СУБД ответ тянет на целую статью.

Comment: я про то, каким именно образом отправляется сам текст запроса,
через сокеты, или поверх tcp, или поверх udp, или поверх http, или поверх еще чего ни-будь

Comment: _каким именно образом отправляется сам текст запроса_, запросы отправляются поверх всего того, что вы перечислили, плюс протоколы, которые разработаны самими производителями СУБД. Решающим является, как сконфигурированно соединение с БД. В чём смысл вашего вопроса, или в каком контексте он возник?

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю, вас интересуют как СУБД обрабатывает SQL-запросы:

1. Парсится запрос
2. Проверяется семантика и права доступа
3. Генерируется план выполнения запроса
4. Оптимизация плана выполнения запроса и выбор наиболее подходящего алгоритма
5. Выполнение непосредственно запроса.

Подробнее в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/processing-a-sql-statement?view=sql-server-2017) (англ) на сайте майкрософт.